# Can't grab data from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

when i use ng-repeat to show data json from php it work but when the data i use for button it can't grap some data. my data grap latitude and longitude from http my controller.js

```
     .controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, kaka, $ionicPopup,  $http){
$scope.item ={};
              $scope.code = {};
              $scope.sizes = [ {code: 123456789, name: 'Modul 1'}, {code: 864369038796946, name: 'Modul 4'},
                                {code: 864369038803833, name: 'Modul 5'}, {code: 864369038816645, name: 'Modul 6'},
                                {code: 864369038797142, name: 'Modul 7'}, {code: 864369038796698, name: 'Modul 8'}];
                $scope.update = function(selected) {
                   $scope.item = selected;
                };
            $scope.rlockbtn = function () {
                kaka.rlock($scope.item.code).success(function (data) {
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                            title: $scope.item.code,
                            template: 'Lock'
                        });                    
                }).error(function (data) {

                });
            };
         $http.get("http://192.168.100.13:88/OMG1/web.php?tN=find")
                      .then(function(response) {
                          $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
                      });
        $scope.find = function () {
                            var mylatlng = {lat: $scope.myWelcome.latitude, lng: $scope.myWelcome.longitude};
                            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                                zoom: 15,
                                center: {lat: -7.3342266, lng: 112.7650341},
                                //center: {lat: data[0].lat, lng: data[0].lng},
                                mapTypeId: 'terrain'
                            });
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: mylatlng,
                                map: map,
                                title: 'Your Motor'
                            });
                    };

        )}
```

this is my html code

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<ion-view view-title="Home">
  <ion-content style="background-color:#818181; background-size: cover;">
    <ion-item  class="row item-text-wrap " >
        <div class="col" style="height: 300px;padding: 0px" id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
    </ion-item><br>
    <form name="form">
    <div class="button-bar">
        <div>

            <select ng-options="size as size.code for size in sizes " ng-model="item" style="background-color:#4d94ff;color: white"ng-change="update(item)"></select>
        </div>           
    </div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                {{myWelcome}}
                <li ng-repeat="x in myWelcome" >
                  {{ x.latitude}}
                  {{ x.longitude}}
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="background-color:#4d94ff;color: white" ng-click="rlockbtn()" >Lock</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="background-color:#4d94ff;color: white" ng-click="unlock()" >Unlock</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="background-color:#4d94ff;color: white" ng-click="engine()" >Engine Off</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="button-bar">

        <button class="icon ion-ios-location btn btn-success btn-lg" style="background-color:#4d94ff;color: white" ng-click="find()" > Find</button>
        <button class="icon ion-map btn btn-success btn-lg" style="background-color:#4d94ff;color: white" ng-click="tracking()" > Tracking</button>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

please help me solve my problem

Comment: Can you please tell us what the exact problem is so that we don't have to waste time guessing?

Comment: What do you mean with when you use the data for the button? Show the example of what is going wrong please

Comment: i have some button to fin posisition (latitude and longitude) if i click button i can't take latitude and longitude to make some marker  but in UI(h1) latitude and longitude can show correctly

Comment: ok, I saw that find function. .myWelcome is an Array, since you use to iterate in ng-repeat. So when you say var mylatlng = {lat: $scope.myWelcome.latitude, lng: $scope.myWelcome.longitude}; It is wrong. Since you have not declarated an index and trying to get the property latitude from an array instead the contained object.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it looks like your myWelcome.latitude and longitude are arrays, so it should be:

```
<ul>
            {{myWelcome}}
            <li ng-repeat="x in myWelcome.latitude" >
              {{ x}}
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="x in myWelcome.longitude" >
              {{ x}}
            </li>
        </ul>
```